# Adding an external image to a custom GWT cell

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm working on a custom cell for a cell list that displays product information including an image and several text fields, similar to the one in the CellList sample. The images are not resources that are packaged with my app, they are on an external image server. I'd like to use UiBinder for the layout of the cell. Eventually the cell will be more complicated, but for now here is a my template that just shows a product description and image:

```
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
  xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

<ui:style>
</ui:style>

<ui:with field="imageSource" type="java.lang.String"/>
<ui:with field="product" type="com.mydomain.ProductProxy" />

<div ui:field="root">
  <span><ui:text from="{product.getDescription}" /></span>
  <ui:image url="{imageSource}" />
</div>
```

The CellList displays a list of descriptions but no products. If I inspect the element with Chrome I can see that the ui:image is not being compiled into an img element:

```
<div onclick="" __idx="0" class="GPROKKBAB" style="outline:none;" tabindex="0">
<div gwtuirendered="gwt-uid-17">
    <span>E03351 </span> 
    <ui:image url="http://images.mydomain.com/image/product_id.jpg"></ui:image>                        </div></div>
```

Any suggestions? I'm sure it's something obvious but I've been at it for a while and I've tried a number of things with no luck.

Comment: Hi, I don't have any experience with UIBinder, but I came accross this : `<g:Image styleName='{style.fortaImage}' resource='{res.fortaLogo}'/>`. The used tag (url versus resource) is different, so may be ^^ Good luck !

Comment: I believe resource is used when the image is part of your distribution and url if it is external. If I put a <g:Image> on the same page with a url field hardcoded to the the one in my example it works, but unfortunately you can't use parameters from render() on any of the g: tags. So it looks like in a custom cell you need to use <ui:image> and that's the one I'm having the problem with.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using an HTML `img`?

```
<img src="{imageSource}" />
```

Comment: You know, I tried that early on and it wasn't working so I probably tried to make it too complicated. I'll give it another shot, there was probably just something wrong with the imageSource parameter I was passing in.